# Is there a way to tell the difference between a parameter in a function being omitted, and the parameter being passed being nil?

Tags: function, lua

Let's say I have a function that returns a Boolean value, and I have a function that sets an override so that the first function always returns a specified Boolean. The second function looks something like this:

```
function override(override, bool)
    bool = bool and true or false --convert to pure Boolean
    
    if override then
        boolOverride = bool
    else
        boolOverride = nil
    end
end
```

However, I want to make it so if bool isn't specified, it will do `bool = not boolOverride`. So that would be something like:

```
function override(override, bool)
    if type(bool) == "nil" then
        bool = not boolOverride
    else
        bool = bool and true or false --convert to pure Boolean
    end
    
    if override then
        boolOverride = bool
    else
        boolOverride = nil
    end
end
```

The problem is, I want it to run the default option `bool = bool and true or false` if the parameter is specifically nil instead of being absent. Is there any difference between the two situations that I could use to make this happen?

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense to me in its current form. `type(bool) == "nil"` can be written as `bool == nil` just as well. `bool = bool and true or false` will be `false` if `bool` is `nil`, so I don't see how that is useful. I also don't see where the override or the returning is supposed to be happening (all I can see is an "override" parameter shadowing the function itself, and a "boolOverride" global variable being set to "bool" or `nil`?); can you please post a minimal, working snippet of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell the difference between a parameter in a function being omitted, and the parameter being passed being nil?

Yes, there is! Lua passes arguments and return values on the stack. There's a difference between "the stack ends here" ("none") and "there's a nil value on the stack". The most straightforward way to distinguish the two is to use `select("#", ...)`, which gives you the count of remaining values on the stack. Let's write a simple function which does one thing if called one argument, another if called with no argument / "nothing" (empty vararg), and errors otherwise:

```lua
function f(...)
    local n = select("#", ...)
    if n == 0 then print"nothing"
    elseif n == 1 then print(...)
    else error"too many arguments" end
end
f() -- nothing
f(nil) -- nil
f(1, 2) -- errors with "too many arguments"
```